# Allow attachment in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have string 'ATTACHMENT REMOVED' in subject of message in Outlook 2021 and I don't have possibility to save it. How to ask Outlook access this attachment?

Outlook Version:
Microsoft® Outlook® LTSC MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188) 64-bit

Comment: You probably can't; it's likely the mail server that has removed the attachment, likely because its malware detection triggered on whatever the attachment was. Does the message provide any more information about the removal? Have you contacted your mail service provider?

Comment: Can you access the attachment via web mail?